# PyDev, shortcut "jump to beginning/end of block"

Tags: python, pydev

I'm looking for a shortcut to jump to the other end of a long code block (can be if, for, while, end of function, class, etc.).
Similar to "go to matching brace" in Visual Studio / C++.

(I've been searching for this sometime now, StackOverflow, Google, ...)

Thanks!

Edit: with "go to matching brace", I meant { and } in C++ and Java

Edit2: I'm also happy with confident answers that say there is no such feature :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift-Alt-Up (Select enclosing scope) works quite well, although it selects the text. But you can then press the right arrow once to deselect, and the cursor should be right at the end of the scope.

An actual "Jump to end of scope" doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Hi jmiserez, I meanwhile switched to another language/platform, but I'm quite confident that this info would have made my life much easier back then!

Answer (score 0):

PyDev (actually Eclipse) has this functionality too. You can find it uder:

> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys

[image]

In the TextEdir widget labeled as **Binding** you can set you key combination.

Note: This is the the functionality that you see en Visual Studio, but it will not works in Python, since **code blocks in python aren't delimited by brackets**. So, this only works with **parentheses** and square **brackets**.

Comment: Thanks Raydel. That indeed exists in the PyDev environment also, and jumps to the matching parantheses (). I#m looking for something that jumps to the end of the block, same effect as matching curly braces {} in java or C++.